# How can I replicate this joint?

Tags: joinery, strength, miter-joint

The picture looks like simple miter but how can I make this a strong miter myself?

[image]

Comment: That is not a good place for such a joint in a chair that sees any sort of regular use. You could do worse than redesign this part of it to make it far stronger than the chair pictured likely is.... if you do it right it could effectively be unbreakable.

Comment: It’s not a chair though but I guess it still applies. Maybe you could elaborate.

Comment: If it's not a chair I presume it's a bench of some kind? I'd need to see more pics of the thing to give better insights, but overall if this is a bench that's much like a widened chair then yes, the same worries still apply pretty much. Chairs are potentially subject to more strain because of the possibility of someone rocking back in it, rare in a bench, but on the other hand a bench might have the weight of 2 or more people so it could balance out..... so, the wider the bench the more vital it becomes that the joint you're asking about is rock solid and strong (overbuild for safety).

Comment: Oh shoot I thought the pillow made it obvious it was a bed. In any case, I meant if you could elaborate on the ‘unbreakable’ joint.

Comment: Oh I thought it was a cushion! If it's a bed then everything changes, since that joint would typically not be stressed much (compared to a chair/bench) or at all (the back rests against a wall), making a complete redesign of the joint no longer relevant. But FFR, that sort of thing is not in the scope of Comments here, which are intended for brief discussions and clarifying questions from potential respondents if there's something unclear in the Q.

Comment: Beds typically experience a lot of racking type forces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my view, the easiest way to make this angle miter stronger is with pocket hole screws and glue. The pocket hole setup only requires the drilling to be done on one piece.  After the holes are set, clamp the two pieces together and insert the screws.
All the normal low price jigs for the other joints are designed for 90^ or straight on joints. 
You could also use the pocket hole jig and create a dowel joint by drill through both pieces from the bottom.  This would require some setup time to determine and shim the guide to obtain the correct angle.  After the hole is cut, insert dowels the normal way. 
Added illustrations of doing either the pockethole or dowel to strengthen the miter joint.

[image]
[image]
To do the dowel, just continue with drill bit into the back piece after clamping together.  Once holes are drilled, short dowels can be inserted in the joint the normal way.

Comment: Does drilling the hole for dowels from the top or bottom make a difference?

Comment: yes, from the bottom piece, the hole can be hidden from view since it is underneath the seat.  If started from the back piece, the starting hole is easily seen.

Answer (score 3):

The indicated joint could be created using mortise and tenon, dowel pins, or biscuits. I suspect the level of strength is in that order as well.

It's less likely that this joint is connected using pocket screws, but you could also accomplish a strong connection in that manner, and fill the screw holes.

Gluing is implied in all cases.

Comment: I guess I thought I wouldn’t have enough room for dowels or pocket holes but I’ll it seems like that’s the easiest way to go

Comment: @mac_33, could you explain what you mean by your thought that you wouldn't have enough room for dowels? I can't visualise why you'd think there wouldn't be enough 'room'.

Comment: It looks to me like if you used pocket screws, you'd be screwing into end grain, which isn't the best practice. Am I missing something here? Is the thought that screws will be strong enough even though it's in end grain? It seems to me that screwing into end grain means the joint would fail faster than one might otherwise expect using pocket screws.

Comment: @Graphus I guess I was looking at it the wrong way when I said that. I thought the holes would be cut from the left side of the bottom piece up into the top piece. Which would mean quickly drilling out through the top piece. Looking at programmer66’s graphic shows drilling from the right with the direction of the top piece.